# Coded UI Search Not Allowing DataService Ajax Request

Tags: mvvm, knockout.js, durandal, coded-ui-tests

I'm creating coded UI tests for my single page application. The application uses durandal.js as the SPA framework. A few other libraries include Knockout.js, TypeScript, and Kendo-UI. Any time the Coded UI test clicks a link or button, the page hangs up. The link seems to be getting clicked by the test. However, directly after the click event, the loading panel appears (spinner) and never goes away.

It seems anytime I perform a codedUI search (see code below) it prevents my dataservice calls. Is it possible the search is blocking the thread? Using the developer toolbar I can see the $.post(url, request) is being called, but I never get a response back. This causes my loading panel (spinner) to stay visible.

```
if (MyHyperlink.WaitForControlExist(7000)) { 
    Mouse.Click(MyHyperlink);
}
```

The code above clicks a hyperlink that shows a grid. The page appears but the grid never appears because the ajax request never returns. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

** Issue only exists while using IE. Google chrome works fine (required the Selenium component)

Comment: I guess you were using selenium for test automation, have you tried phantomjs just to verify its not related to the browser?

Comment: @zewa666 Thanks for the comment. I'm not using Selenium since I assumed this isn't required when using IE10. Is this a correct assumption? I'm unfamiliar with Phantom.js and will look into it. Thanks!

Comment: So is what you are using the MS default test automation lib? Have no experience with that one but Ive successfully tested with selenium and phantomjs. Later one is a headless Browser awesome for fast e2e Tests. Google for tuts.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your app.config

Someone can probably explain this better, but basically what is happening is this:

`CodedUI` is opening and blocking the same port that IE uses for Ajax requests. Setting `WebWaitForReadyLevel = 3` prevents this from happening.